# Nginx - How to add multiple values to header

Tags: nginx

I have a header that is not taking in nginx. Say I have a header such as `Strict-Transport-Securty`.

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security    'max-age=31536000; preload'  always;
```

Should `max-age` and `preload` be separated by a semi-colon and a space? No space? Commas only? How do I include multiple values? The [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) nginx docs don't mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semicolon is the correct way of separating `Strict-Transport-Securty` header values. Your line

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; preload' always;
```

is correct.

---

You probably weren't able to find it in the Nginx docs because this is standardized in the [IETF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797):

> ```
> Strict-Transport-Security = "Strict-Transport-Security" ":"
>                             [ directive ]  *( ";" [ directive ] )
> ```

---

See here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1